# Clicking 'Search' and 'Enter' buttons with Detox on ios keyboard

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, automation, detox

Trying to get Detox to click the 'Search' and 'Enter' buttons on the ios simulator keyboard and am not having much luck.  I saw on their git issue page someone recommended using `await element(by.label('return')).tap();` but I am having no luck and am not really sure where to start.  Wondering if anyone here has had any luck doing so

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `\n` after the text, the keyboard automatically selects `return` or `enter` key command and closes soft keyboard.

```
await element(by.id("text_input")).toBeVisible();
await element(by.id("text_input")).typeText("type some thing \n")
```

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/209#issuecomment-317201130)

Comment: Turns out it was just by.label('Search')
It didn't seem to like my lowercase
The stacktrace detox gives is not very useful haha